# Delete all resource routing in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, crud

I have this line in my routes file:

```
resources :tags
```

I need to add a route for deleting all the tags in one go.  How would I add this to my routes file and would the corresponding action be in the same controller or not?

Comment: You could set this up however you wanted to.  I wouldn't recommend trying to find some way to hack the `resources :tags` bit, just add a new route and set up the corresponding controller method to handle what you want it to do and you are good to go.  Just because you are deleting tags does not mean it has to be in the tags controller, although since it is so closly related it would probably help to put it there, but it really depends on your app.  It could go anywhere though.

Comment: @RockwellRice So if I wrote my link like:  `<%= link_to "Delete all tags", admin_tags_path, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>`.   Would the resources :tags   destroy action work with just a conditional on params[:id] work?    OR, as you said above, would I need a separate `match 'tags', to: 'tags#destroy_all', via: :delete` line?

Comment: You would need a separate action most likely, unless you sent a request specifically for each tag, like in a loop or something, but that wouldn't be a good idea imho.  I think to get a clear answer you need to provide more details about what you tried to set up.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Rails conventions, the destroy action is reserved to destroy one record. So here I would generate a custom route. 
I would also link it to the tags controller.

```
resources :tags do 
  collection do 
    delete 'delete_all_tags'
  end
end
```

```
class TagsController < ApplicationController

  def delete_all_tags
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Fantastic. Will try this this evening. Thank you.  I wasn't sure what the convention was which is one of the reasons I asked

Comment: I've just added this but `rake routes` shows the path as "destoy_all_tags_admin_tags".  Is there a way to make it be "admin_tags_destroy_all_tags" instead?

Comment: This is just a cosmetic thing, but you can use `:as` in the routes. Look here:
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#naming-routes
and here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#using-as-in-nested-resources